# Is there a way to make the taskbar 'fill' from the bottom first? [Windows 10]

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I am using Windows 10. I wonder if there is a way to make the taskbar 'fill' from the bottom first once it has been expanded? I have unlocked it and expanded it by one unit up, and have several quick launch buttons on it. I would like to have the buttons on the bottom of the task bar, and the open programs/folders start at the bottom too, before filling the upper segment.

I tried a google search and could only see information about changing the regular settings in the settings panel, none of which are the setting I am after. I am comfortable to add things to the registry that will work.

[A picture made in paint of both how it looks now and how I would like it to display.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7TRz.png)

Thank you for looking into this problem.